# getting select value from a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is an sql query that im using to get a list of users who doest have contact details added. The below query seems to work fine. But the only problem is that the image value always returns `NULL`

I tried to use a sub query to image the image link.Everything works except for the image link.

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,a.address,a.image_id,(select url 
                                         from meta_details b 
                                         where b.p_id = 'a.image_id' 
                                         and b.meta_val='profile_pic') as image 
FROM users 
WHERE a.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM details where contact_id != '$cid')
```

Im not sure if this is the correct way, is it possible to make it work to get the image url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the quote around  a.image_id ( otherwise instead of a join condition on field  you have a join on literal value `'a.image_id'` that fails because don't match )

```
SELECT 
    a.id
   ,a.name
   ,a.address
   ,a.image_id
   ,(select url 
          from meta_details b 
          where b.p_id = a.image_id and b.meta_val='profile_pic' ) as image 
FROM users a
WHERE a.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM details where contact_id != '$cid')
```

Comment: and also define alias for table user **FROM users a**

Comment: @BerndBuffen   .  correct  ..thanks  answer  updated

Answer (score 0):

This type of query can also be expressed with `join` operations:

```
select u.*, md.url as image
from users u left join
     meta_details md
     on md.p_id = u.image_id and 
        md.meta_val = 'profile_pic' left join
     details d
     on d.user_id = u.user_id and d.contact_id <> '$cid'
where d.user_id is null;
```

The advantage to this approach is that the SQL optimizer has a chance of producing a better optimization plan.  Also, `NOT IN` is dangerous because if any rows from the subquery return `NULL`, then no rows at all will be returned from the query.